# MS Access - Subform navigation

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba, subform

I have created a main form for data entry.  It contains a subform to apply the main form's data to several different "customers". Everything works fine and data goes exactly where I want it to.

However, I'm having one minor issue. The subform contains a single combo box, used to select a customer, and the form is in *Continuous Forms* view.  I want the user to be able to click the drop down to choose a customer, and upon hitting enter and/or tab, go to the combo box in the next subform row and begin typing without having to click there.

I'm new to VBA and don't want to create an event upon enter/tab that potentially affects my data entry.  Is there another way to accomplish my goal?

Comment: *"The next combo box"* means a new row in the subform, right?  If so, check the "Cycle" property on the "Other" tab of the subform's property sheet --- see whether setting it to "All Records" gives you what you want.

Comment: Not sure if I follow, but you can press _Ctrl-PgDn_ to go to the next record same field.

Comment: have you tried setting the focus on change?

Comment: @HansUp Wow, what an incredibly simple solution that fixed it exactly as I'd hoped. That's all it took, thanks much!

Comment: You're welcome.  I submitted that as an answer.  Also edited your question to hopefully avoid any more close votes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the *"Cycle"* property on the *"Other"* tab of the subform's property sheet.
Choose *"All Records"* from that property's drop down box.

Since the subform contains only a combo box for each row, the result from that setting change should be that pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Tab</kbd> after making a selection should take you to the next row in the subform.  And when you're already at the subform "last row", you will wind up at the "new row".